# How to send a json block to the user as a file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, file, express

I have a big JSON block; what is the best way to send it to browser as a (downloaded) file?

Here is an example if my source was from a file, but in my case my source is not a file it is a variable and I need to send this json data to the browser:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.jpg");
var request = http.get("http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

My attempted code:

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=myData.json');
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
//data is my variable with my JSON block
res.pipe(data);//This is not right!
```

If my question is vague, please let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: What's the actual result with this code?

Comment: @DanielKaplan For my attempted code: error: Object #<Object> has no method 'on

Comment: Try `res.write(data, "binary")` or `res.write(new Buffer(data.toString("binary"), "binary"));`

Comment: @bhantol None of them is working; the first one says the first param needs to be buffer and the second one's loading never ends! btw I used them with my attempted headers.

Comment: Try `just res.end(new Buffer(data, "binary"))`

Comment: @bhantol res.end(new Buffer(data, "binary")) is not returning anything neither a file nor any output; just empty content; although data is a big block json data (not empty); I have user it with my header and without my headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what type of frameworks you're using (Express?), but this works with just the plain http module.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment;   filename=myfilename');

  var data = { foo: 'bar' };      

  res.write(JSON.stringify(data))
  res.end()

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: But this is just showing the result in the browser; I want it as a file downloaded to the browser

Comment: That has to do with your browser's settings, you have it set so that it opens the file (which in this case will be a .txt file). Why was my answer downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you might want, instead, is JSON streaming. EG: You want to send a very large JSON object to a client in pieces (not all at once, wasting a lot of memory).

There's a pretty nice library which handles this for you, here: https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream

Comment: No I'm not interested in streaming; I just want to have my data variable which is a JSON block as a downloaded file in the browser.

Comment: If that's the case, then the *only* think you need to do is output a separate Content-Type header for the user. This is the only thing that determines whether or not code is shown as a file or whatever.

Comment: Could you please elaborate it? I did not understand! Thanks